# Git "revert" current directory

Tags: git, version-control, reset, git-checkout, revert

In Subversion (SVN), it's possible to do `svn revert ./*` in which the current directory and *only* the current directory gets reverted.

What is the Git equivalent to `svn revert` in which only the current directory gets reverted?

I know that there's `git reset --hard`, but it reverts everything and not just the current directory.

How would I revert just the current directory in Git?

Comment: Use `git checkout` instead of reset.

Comment: `git checkout <branchname>~1 -- path/to/directory/you/want/updated` should do the trick.  The ~1 after the branch name means back one commit.

Comment: it does not delete new files within workin dir as SVN would do, can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Like [vcsjones says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14125385/git-revert-current-directory#comment19553456_14125385), the solution here is `git checkout`:

```
git checkout <refspec> -- path/to/directory  # or path/to/file
```

where `<refspec>` can, for instance, be `HEAD`, that is, the current working commit. Note that this usage of the `checkout` command will affect the working tree *but not the index*.

`git revert` is used to "revert a commit", and by this, it should *not* be understood that the commit disappears from the tree (it would play havoc with history -- if you want that, look at `git rebase -i`). A reverted commit consists of applying, *in reverse*, all changes from the commit given as an argument to the tree and create a *new commit* with the changes (with a default commit message, which you can modify).

Comment: Doesn't work if you added files in your current branch (and if those files have unique and different names). Within my branch, I had to delete the folder and then checkout the folder again: `rm folder -rf && git checkout origin/master folder/`

Answer (score 42):

Go to the folder you want to revert and do this:

```
git checkout -- .
```

See more in [krlmlr's answer to *How to git reset --hard a subdirectory*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404535/how-to-git-reset-hard-a-subdirectory/16589534#16589534).

Comment: This work great if your change are not already added in your next commit.

Answer (score 7):

When I was a Git novice (and afraid of the terminal) I found the easiest way was to:

- switch to the branch you want to revert your specific subdirectory to
- copy the subdirectory you want to revert to your desktop
- switch back to your branch
- overwrite the subdirectory you want to replace in your Git directory with the one you copied to your desktop

Comment: @saeraphin Perhaps I've misunderstood something, but how does this not work? When I was a git novice (and probably still am) this worked perfectly and is easy to understand. I don't use subversion and do not know what "svn revert" does but to revert a sub directory to that of another branch or another commit, this works. It's also not scary for new people using the terminal.

Comment: okay, I misread one word. I still find the command line more efficient though. I will gladly remove the down vote if you're kind enough to replace "noobs" by something less offensive.

Comment: @saeraphin Done

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it recursively from a specific directory:

```sh
git checkout -- ./*
git checkout -- mydir/*
```