# How to rewrite a branch, discarding changes to a subfolder

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-reset

I need to rewrite a branch, discarding all changes made to a specific subfolder (e.g. whose path is `path/to/folder`) and its contents between a range of revisions starting at a specified `start` revision and ending at `HEAD`. Changes prior to the `start` revision are accepted.

I've considered using `git-filter-branch` to do this, but don't know what filter to use. I think using 'git-reset' to the subfolder for each commit might work, but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404535/how-to-git-reset-hard-a-subdirectory) has me questioning whether this approach will work.

Question: How do I rewrite the branch as specified in the first paragraph above?

Comment: provide an example, please?

Comment: as I understand the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) you should be good with `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/folder' commit..HEAD`

Comment: This would remove path/to/folder completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked was using `git-filter-branch` with a combination of `git rm` to remove new files added in commits and 'git checkout' to restore the state.

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rfq -- path/to/subdir && git checkout -f <the-good-state-sha1> -- path/to/subdir' -- start..HEAD
```

Here `start` is the starting commit and `<the-good-state-sha1>` is the hash of `start`'s parent commit. **Note**: `path/to/subdir` needs to be specified twice as shown, once in the `rm` command and once in the `checkout` command.

Answer (score 2):

Use [git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) with `--tree-filter`, probably with `--prune-empty`. The whole command sequence could be like this:

```
GOOD_STATE=<some-revision>
DIR_TO_PRESERVE="relative/path/to/directory"
BRANCH_TO_REWRITE=<branch-to-rewrite>
export GOOD_STATE DIR_TO_PRESERVE BRANCH_TO_REWRITE
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
    'rm -rf "${DIR_TO_PRESERVE}" && git checkout -f ${GOOD_STATE} -- "${DIR_TO_PRESERVE}"' \
    --prune-empty ${BRANCH_TO_REWRITE} --not ${GOOD_STATE}
```

As a faster alternative `--index-filter` can be used. But as a command you shouldn't use `git rm...` because this would remove the path completely. Instead you should reset the index for a given folder using `git reset`:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git reset -q ${GOOD_STATE} -- "${DIR_TO_PRESERVE}"'' \
    --prune-empty ${BRANCH_TO_REWRITE} --not ${GOOD_STATE}
```

To speed up things one could temporarily copy the repository to a faster filesystem (I used `tmpfs` on Linux for that, and 9007 commits have been rewritten using --index-filter in 14 min 37 seconds).

Comment: Hmm - I tried to use --index-filter with the same command on a trivial test repo and it seemed to work. However on the actual repo with thousands of commits, it does not. Could you please provide a full command line to use with --index-filter? Also, some explanation of what is going on would be great. I don't quite understand how it does what it does.